# Mongoose works only under node.js?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question About mongoosejs, http://mongoosejs.com/ it works only under Node.Js? 
How I can use it in Angular js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mongoose.js is a server-side library for use in node.js. You can certainly build your application's web interface in angular.js and the server side business logic in mongoose.js, though. For example, in the MEAN stack, you would could angular.js for the web interface, express.js for the API server and mongoose.js for persisting data to mongodb.